# Sending JSON to AJAX using PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm trying to show the data received in a little python3 script when a button is clicked in a website without refreshing. To achieve this I have chosen PHP to execute the python3 script and AJAX to show it. My problem is when it comes to showing the data.

The python script to create the json:

```
!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

def receive_json():
    message = {'num1':1, 'num2':2, 'num3':3}
    print(json.dumps(message))

receive_json()
```

The AJAX code in the website to show the message received:

```
<div class="row">
  <table class ="center">
    <tr>
      <td id="plot2">num2</td>
      <td id="plot3">num3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id = "actualDataButton">
  <button type="button"  onclick="callPHPscript()">Get actual data</button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function callPHPscript(){
        $.ajax({
          url:'getData.php', //the page containing php script
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success:function(result){
            $("#plot2").html(result[1]);
            $("#plot3").html(result[2]);
          }
        });
      }
  </script>

</div>
```

The php script called getData.php:

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/Users/Borjis/Sites/receive_json.py');
$output = shell_exec($command); //JSON received
$json = json_decode($output);
$array = array($json->num1,$json->num2,$json->num3);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

When I run this, the table doesn't show anything, it's not null, the content its empty. But if I change the $array in PHP with the received JSON variables to an array of numbers, like this:

> $array = array(1,2,3); 
>   The table shows the correct values 2 and 3 in the correct place.

I have tried to send the JSON received in PHP in the $output variable without modifying, to utf8_encode the JSON received...

If I put:

> $array = array(1,2,$json->num3);
>   It only shows the value 2

When I run the PHP script in the CLI it always shows values, from JSON or putting the numbers in the array. The problem is when it comes to decode it in AJAX.

I only want to show the JSON values on the website.

Comment: Could you show a var_dump($json); in php file?

Comment: What is the result of PHP script?
pls run it in browser and paste here

Comment: and console.log(result) after `success:function(result){`

Comment: @DavitHuroyan When I run it with $array = array($json->num1,$json->num2,$json->num3); it shows [1,2,3]

Comment: @DmytroHuz It shows ["num1"]=>int(1) ["num2"]=>int(2) ["num3"]=>int(3)

Comment: @DmytroHuz The console.log(result) value is Array(3) [null, null, null]

Comment: @Borjis var_dump($json->num1) returns anything? and var_dump($json['num1'])

Comment: @DmytroHuz var_dump($json->num1) returns int(1) and var_dump($json['num1']) returns Cannot use object of type stdClass as array, Stack trace: #0 {main}

Comment: Your shebang is missing an `#`. Also, since your python script already returns JSON, why do you `json_decode()` and then `json_encode()` it again? Seems overhead to me

Comment: @Borjis  it looks very strange. ok let's try last thing: var_dump(json_encode($array))

Comment: @DmytroHuz it returns string(7) "[1,2,3]"

Comment: @kerbholz i didn't put the # because it made the text bold, and i have tried to send the $output but it returns the same, its only one of the 100000 versions I have made trying

Comment: Try to delete `dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` from ajax. And make console.log(result) again. And also check in 'Network' tab in the browser what result server sends.

Comment: @DmytroHuz Ok, in the console tab it says [null, null, null] and in the network tab it says in getData.php response Content-Length: 7. It seems like getData.php sends the data but AJAX its not decoding it properly.

Comment: It should work then. Everything looks pretty well. At least ajax should show a row data, when you deleted what I asked. I even don't know what you could try more =(

Comment: @DmytroHuz Yeah, I know, its a little bit weird. I will try it in another computer to see if it works and try another ways to make it work. Thank you so much for your time! :D

Comment: No problem. It is a good idea. Let me know about the result.  Very interesting where is a problem =)

Answer (score 1):

Run your python script in CLI to see if it delivers the expected output. (I had to make mine executable) If it does, run your `getData.php` script to see if it returns the expected output.

Since your python script already returns JSON I would change `getData.php` to the following, so it simply returns the data received from your python script:

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/Users/Borjis/Sites/receive_json.py');
$output = shell_exec($command); //JSON received
echo $output;
?>
```

Now, since your output from `getData.php` should be

```
{'num1':1, 'num2':2, 'num3':3}
```

change your javascript code to access the keys from your JSON. Change

```
success:function(result){
  $("#plot2").html(result[1]);
  $("#plot3").html(result[2]);
}
```

to

```
success:function(result){
  $("#plot2").html(result['num2']);
  $("#plot3").html(result['num3']);
}
```

Comment: it is just an optimisation of the code. it won't fix a problem, as I can see

Comment: Well, it fixed it for me. OPs code didn't work on my server, mine does

Comment: ah...ok. Great then ;)

Comment: Like I said before I have tried to echo the $output variable without encoding it in PHP because it is JSON, but it doesn't work this way either. Python script works, PHP script works in CLI but when it comes to AJAX receiving the data something is going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried running `getData.php` in your browser? Anything in your browser console? The "Network" tab lets you see the requests/responses.

Comment: When I run it in the browser the network tab it says in getData.php response Content-Length: 7 but when I see the console tab looking for the return of console.log(result) it shows [null, null, null]

Comment: Probably no need for `console.log(result)`, the "Network" tab in your browser tools has "sub"-tabs to view the response. Okaaay, when you say you tested `receive_json.py` in CLI it worked, how did you call that script? `python3 receive_json.py`? Because using `escapeshellcmd` you need to make the `receive_json.py` executable first for it to work.

Comment: Yes, in the CLI I run it with python3 receive_json.py. And I made it executable. The problem here is on the PHP script or the AJAX script.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the JSON response as an Object and access member variables with the "." operator.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function callPHPscript(){
            $.ajax({
              url:'getData.php', //the page containing php script
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              success:function(result){
                var r=JSON.parse(result); // Store your JSON response in a variable to access the response 
                $("#plot2").html(r.num2);
                $("#plot3").html(r.num3);
              }
            });
          }
      </script>
```

Comment: I have tried it before with $("#plot2").html(result.num2);  but it doesn't show anything either.

Comment: What do var_dump($output); and var_dump($json); print?

Comment: var_dump($output) returns string(34) "{"num1": 1, "num2": 2, "num3": 3}" and var_dump($json) returns object(stdClass)#1 (3) {["num1"]=>int(1) ["num2"]=>int(2) ["num3"]=> int(3)}

Comment: Strange. That part looks OK. What does console.log(result); display in the browser console? That should help us narrow down on the output from the PHP script.

Comment: The console.log(result) returns (3) [null, null, null]. I think its a problem with PHP sending the $json->num1 variables...

Comment: But if I try to create var r = JSON.parse(result) and then $("#plot2").html(r.num2); the console outputs "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 0"

Comment: That will give an exception because you are no longer storing the keys num1, num2, num3 in $array. You are only saving the values 1,2,3. Before sending the output, just do this - $encoded_values=json_encode($array); echo $encoded_values; See what you get.

Comment: It gives me an exception when I put the var r = JSON.parse(result); line, so I just remove it. I think it happens because dataType: json parse the result before.And It gives me nothing even If I put json_encode($array).

Comment: Accessing getdata.php directly, echo json_encode($array); prints [1,2,3] on the browser.

Comment: Not in my case, when i run it in the CLI it works but not in the browser with console.log(results) or showing the return in the HTML table.